# Data List isn't showing up in the Recycler View in the main activity in android app , using kotlin for development.

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, kotlin

activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sampleex_recycleview.himanshu.recycleview.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecViewId"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Data List for RecyclerView in main activity, list_row.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:padding="25dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AgeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NameTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:hint="age"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:hint="name"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Main Activity code here :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var adapter : PersonListAdapter? = null
private var layoutManager : RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var personList : ArrayList<Person>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    personList = ArrayList<Person>()
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = PersonListAdapter(personList!!, this)

    //set up recycle view
    RecViewId.layoutManager = layoutManager
    RecViewId.adapter = adapter

    // loading data
    for(i in 1..15){
        var person = Person()
        person.name = "Person " + i
        person.age = 21 + i
    }

    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

  }
}
```

Adapter Class' code (exists in package name 'Data') : 
// adapter class for the inflating layout for list in the recycler view and parsing data into the feild components of the layout

```
class PersonListAdapter(private var list : ArrayList<Person>, var context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {

    holder?.bindItem(list[position])
}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return  list.size
}

    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

   fun bindItem(person: Person){
       var Name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameTextView) as TextView
       var Age : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AgeTextView) as TextView
        Name.text = person.name
        Age.text = person.age.toString()
    }
  }

}
```

Person Class' code (exists in different package name 'Model'): 
// class for the layout of the data to be shown in the data list in the Recycler view in the main activity

```
class Person{
    var name : String? = null
    var age : Int? = null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your just creating person object. Those objects need to be added to the personList.

```
 for(i in 1..15){
    var person = Person()
    person.name = "Person " + i
    person.age = 21 + i
    personList.add(person) // Add person object to the list
}
```

Also you aren't correctly initializing the RecyclerView in the above code.

```
//set up recycle view
val recView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RecViewId)
recView.layoutManager = layoutManager
recView.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and set fixed size for RecyclerView